# RuntimeError: Given groups=1, weight of size [32, 1, 3, 3], expected input[1, 8, 128, 128] to have 1 channels, but got 8 channels instead

Tags: python, deep-learning, pytorch, computer-vision, conv-neural-network

getting above error after implementing below code ,i have images and corresponding annoation of facial keypoint in text file ,
want to train cnn model in pytorch to detect facial keypoint.
the format of text file in which keypoints are as below

```
x1,y1
x2,y2
...
```

and so on and images are in seperate folder with png format

```
import os
import cv2
import numpy as np
import torch
from torch.utils.data import Dataset
from torchvision.transforms import ToTensor, transforms

class FaceKeypointDataset(Dataset):
    def __init__(self, image_folder_path, keypoint_folder_path, transform=None):
        self.image_folder_path = image_folder_path
        self.keypoint_folder_path = keypoint_folder_path
        self.transform = transform
        self.image_filenames = [os.path.splitext(f)[0] for f in os.listdir(image_folder_path) if f.endswith('.png') or f.endswith('.jpg')]
        self.keypoint_filenames = [os.path.splitext(f)[0] for f in os.listdir(keypoint_folder_path) if f.endswith('.txt')]

    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.image_filenames)

    def __getitem__(self, idx):
        image_path = os.path.join(self.image_folder_path, self.image_filenames[idx] + '.png')
        keypoint_path = os.path.join(self.keypoint_folder_path, self.keypoint_filenames[idx] + '.txt')
        # print(image_path , '--', keypoint_path)
        image = cv2.imread(image_path, cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)
        keypoint = np.loadtxt(keypoint_path, delimiter=',')
        # Normalize keypoint coordinates to [-1, 1]
        keypoint[:, 0] = (keypoint[:, 0] / image.shape[1]) * 2 - 1
        keypoint[:, 1] = (keypoint[:, 1] / image.shape[0]) * 2 - 1

        if self.transform:
            image = Image.fromarray(image) # convert numpy ndarray to PIL Image
            image = self.transform(image)

        return image, torch.from_numpy(keypoint).float()

transform = transforms.Compose([transforms.Resize(128),
                                transforms.Grayscale(num_output_channels=1),
                                transforms.ToTensor()])

class FaceKeypointCNN(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.conv1 = nn.Conv2d(1, 32, kernel_size=3, padding=1)
        self.pool1 = nn.MaxPool2d(kernel_size=2, stride=2)
        self.conv2 = nn.Conv2d(32, 64, kernel_size=3, padding=1)
        self.pool2 = nn.MaxPool2d(kernel_size=2, stride=2)
        self.conv3 = nn.Conv2d(64, 128, kernel_size=3, padding=1)
        self.pool3 = nn.MaxPool2d(kernel_size=2, stride=2)
        self.conv4 = nn.Conv2d(128, 256, kernel_size=3, padding=1)
        self.pool4 = nn.MaxPool2d(kernel_size=2, stride=2)
        self.fc1 = nn.Linear(256 * 32 * 32, 1024)
        self.fc2 = nn.Linear(1024, 136)

    def forward(self, x):
        x = self.conv1(x)
        x = F.relu(x)
        x = self.pool1(x)
        x = self.conv2(x)
        x = F.relu(x)
        x = self.pool2(x)
        x = self.conv3(x)
        x = F.relu(x)
        x = self.pool3(x)
        x = self.conv4(x)
        x = F.relu(x)
        x = self.pool4(x)
        x = x.view(x.size(0), -1)
        x = self.fc1(x)
        x = F.relu(x)
        x = self.fc2(x)

        return x

def train(model, train_loader, criterion, optimizer, device):
    model.train()
    train_loss = 0.0
    for images, keypoints in train_loader:
        images, keypoints = images.to(device), keypoints.to(device)
        
        # Remove extra dimension from images
        images = images.squeeze(1)
        
        optimizer.zero_grad()
        outputs = model(images)
        loss = criterion(outputs, keypoints)
        loss.backward()
        optimizer.step()
        train_loss += loss.item() * images.size(0)
        
    return train_loss / len(train_loader.dataset)



def evaluate(model, val_loader, criterion, device):
    model.eval()
    running_loss = 0.0
    with torch.no_grad():
        for data in val_loader:
            inputs, labels = data
            inputs = inputs.unsqueeze(1).float().to(device)
            labels = labels.float().to(device)
            outputs = model(inputs)
            loss = criterion(outputs, labels)
            running_loss += loss.item()
    return running_loss / len(val_loader)


def save_best_model(model, val_loss, best_val_loss, model_save_path):
    if val_loss < best_val_loss:
        torch.save(model.state_dict(), model_save_path)
        print(f"Saved best model with validation loss {val_loss:.4f}")
        return val_loss
    return best_val_loss


if __name__ == "__main__":
    # Define hyperparameters
    image_folder_path = "/content/drive/MyDrive/kaggle/Task 1/ann_done"
    keypoint_folder_path = "/content/drive/MyDrive/kaggle/Task 1/ann"
    model_save_path = "/content/drive/MyDrive/kaggle/Task 1/model.pth"
    batch_size = 8
    learning_rate = 0.001
    num_epochs = 20
    test_ratio = 0.2
    val_ratio = 0.2
    random_seed = 42

    # Define device (GPU if available, else CPU)
    device = torch.device("cuda" if torch.cuda.is_available() else "cpu")
    print(f"Using device: {device}")

    # Define dataset and transforms
    dataset = FaceKeypointDataset(image_folder_path, keypoint_folder_path, transform=transform)

    # Split dataset into train, validation, and test sets
    num_data = len(dataset)
    num_test = int(num_data * test_ratio)
    num_val = int(num_data * val_ratio)
    num_train = num_data - num_test - num_val
    train_set, val_set, test_set = random_split(dataset, [num_train, num_val, num_test],
                                                 generator=torch.Generator().manual_seed(random_seed))

    # Define data loaders
    train_loader = DataLoader(train_set, batch_size=batch_size, shuffle=True)
    val_loader = DataLoader(val_set, batch_size=batch_size, shuffle=False)


    # Define model, loss function, and optimizer
    model = FaceKeypointCNN().to(device)
    criterion = nn.MSELoss()
    optimizer = optim.Adam(model.parameters(), lr=learning_rate)

    # Train model and save best model based on validation loss
    best_val_loss = np.inf
    for epoch in range(num_epochs):
        train_loss = train(model, train_loader, criterion, optimizer, device)
        val_loss = evaluate(model, val_loader, criterion, device)
        print(f"Epoch {epoch+1}/{num_epochs}, train loss: {train_loss:.4f}, val loss: {val_loss:.4f}")
        best_val_loss = save_best_model(model, val_loss, best_val_loss, model_save_path)

    # Load best model and evaluate on test set
    model.load_state_dict(torch.load(model_save_path))
    test_loss = evaluate(model, test_loader, criterion, device)
    print(f"Test loss: {test_loss:.4f}")
```

Answer (score 0):

I would first state that this question should not have been asked here as there are a huge number of other questions facing exactly the same issue, and while these questions may not have exactly the same verbatim code change required to resolve the issue, they are structurally homologous and the approaches used to solve these issues could have and should have been applied here. (For instance, you should print the shapes of various tensors at various points in code execution to determine when the dimensions of things start to differ from what is expected.)

That being said, your particular issue is caused by `images = images.squeeze(1)`, which changes the shape of images from `[8,1,128,128]` to `[8,128,128]`. `nn.Conv2d` expects inputs to be 4-dimensional `[batch_size,n_channels,height,width]` even if the number of channels is 1.

Solving this issue, you will likely have another error due to size mismatch at `self.fc1`. You should be able to solve this by using the same method of printing tensor shapes during execution.